# What is an example of an open set in $\mathbb{R}^2$ which is a Cartesian product of two non-open sets in $\mathbb{R}$?

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, analysis

What is an example of an open set in $\mathbb{R}^2$ which is a Cartesian product of two non-open sets in $\mathbb{R}$?

Is this possible? I can only come up two open sets in $\mathbb{R}$? i.e (0,1) x (0,1)

What about one open set and one non-open set?

Answer (score 5):

This is impossible, because the linear projections from $\mathbb{R}^2$ to 
$\mathbb{R}$ are open maps. So if $A\times B$ is open set in $\mathbb{R}^2$ 
then $\pi_1(A\times B)=A$ is open set on $\mathbb{R}$.

Answer (score 3):

This is not possible. Let $A \subset \mathbb{R}$ be a non-open set. Then there exists a point $a \in A$ such that there lie points outside $A$ arbitrarily close to $a$. Let $B \subset \mathbb{R}$ be any non-empty set, $b \in B$ any point, and consider the point $(a,b) \in A \times B \subset \mathbb{R}^2$. Then there lie points $(x,y)$ with $x \notin A$ arbitrarily close to $(a,b)$. So $A \times B$ is not open.

Comment: What about one open set and one non-open set?

Comment: If the open set is not empty the argument I stated still works.